# I have found a sample online for dart I’d like to ask how this works

Tags: for-loop, dart

In dart for loops seem to not make much sense. This sample has a for loop which will only stop when i < 5 which should mean that the loop stops when i is less than 5, but the starting value is less than 5.

````
    ```
    void main() {
      for (int i = 0; i  5; i++) {
        print('hello ${i + 1}');
      }
 ```
 ```    

   The output is:
Hello world 1
Hello world 2
Hello world 3
Hello world 4
Hello world 5
  ```
````

Comment: `for loop which will only stop when i < 5` ... are you certain of this?

Answer (score 0):

The value of i in your for loop starts at 0 and ends at 4. Basically what is happening is this:

```
Hello world 0 + 1
Hello world 1 + 1
Hello world 2 + 1
Hello world 3 + 1
Hello world 4 + 1
```

The exact value of i isn't directly printed since it is being modified in the string interpolation i.e. `${i + 1}`. The loop terminates when the value of i hits 4 but what gets printed is 4 + 1.

The reason it stops there and not at 0 (which you claim is less than 5 and a valid time to terminate) is because for loops iterate over a range. By stating `i = 0` and `i < 5` we are telling the compiler to execute the code block n times, where n is the difference between the lower limit provided (0) and the upper limit (4). `i++` increases the value of i until the condition `i < 5` is no longer satisfied hence why we have an upper limit of 4.

Comment: it makes sense now I see how it terminates when i = 5 rather than when i is less than 5